# Python-3.4 open a python file and look for the name of functions

Tags: python, file

When a Python file is open for reading via

```
read_file = open(input_file, "r"))
```

how can we find the name of functions from the open python file and print them?

Answer (score 0):

With [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir):

> Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.

```
>>> read_file = open('test.txt', 'r')
>>> dir(read_file)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'close', 'closed', 'encoding', 'errors', 'fileno', 'flush', 'isatty', 'mode', 'name', 'newlines', 'next', 'read', 'readinto', 'readline', 'readlines', 'seek', 'softspace', 'tell', 'truncate', 'write', 'writelines', 'xreadlines']
```

Comment: Um, that's printing the attributes of the `read_file` file object, not the functions defined in 'test.txt', which for the purposes of the question should be a Python source file.

Answer (score 0):

`ast` to the rescue!

```
import ast

with open('somefile.py', 'r') as fin:
    source = fin.read()

tree = ast.parse(source)

class FuncFinder(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.function_names = []


    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        self.function_names.append(node.name)
        self.generic_visit(node)

finder = FuncFinder()
finder.visit(tree)
print(finder.function_names)
```

Copy/paste-able working demo:

```
source = """
def foo():
  pass

def bar():
  pass

class FooBar(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
"""

import ast

tree = ast.parse(source)

class FuncFinder(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.function_names = []


    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        self.function_names.append(node.name)
        self.generic_visit(node)

finder = FuncFinder()
finder.visit(tree)
print(finder.function_names)  # ['foo', 'bar', '__init__']
```

Note that we get **all** the function names (including those in classes, nested inside of other functions, etc).  You could easily skip those by adding `def visit_ClassDef(self, node): pass` ...

Comment: That was some fast coding.

Comment: @simonzack -- Thanks.  It was _almost_ right.  Turns out that `NodeVisitor.visit` doesn't return `self` (and for whatever reason, I always want it to).